# Обход троичного дерева

Tags: алгоритм

Имеется стандартное троичное дерево. Добавляем в него элементы:

```
TT_insert( tree, "a" );
TT_insert( tree, "aa" );
TT_insert( tree, "b" );
TT_insert( tree, "bb" );
```

При обходе этого дерева по узлам "меньше-равно-больше" (ну или left-middle-right, LMR) встречаем элементы в таком порядке:

```
"aa"
"a"
"bb"
"b"
```

При обходе в обратном направлении (RML), соответственно:

```
"bb"
"b"
"aa"
"a"
```

А как получить элементы в таком порядке?

```
"a"
"aa"
"b"
"bb"
```

Кроме как реверсировать массив, полученный во втором варианте, ничего в голову на ночь глядя не приходит.

P.S. Выложил [исходники дерева](https://github.com/klopp/TTree). Например:

```
#include "ttree.h"
static void t_print( TernaryTreeNode node, void * data )
{
    printf( "%s\n", node->key );
}
int main()
{
    TernaryTree t = TT_create( TT_DEFAULTS, NULL );

    TT_insert( t, "a", NULL );
    TT_insert( t, "aa", NULL );
    TT_insert( t, "b", NULL );
    TT_insert( t, "bb", NULL );

    TT_dump( t, stdout );
    TT_reverse_walk( t, t_print, NULL );
    TT_destroy( t );
    return 0;
}
```

На выходе:

```
[21:13:03] Debug $ ./ttree
nodes: 5, keys: 4
+-a => [a]
  |-a => [aa]
  +-b => [b]
    +-b => [bb]
bb
b
aa
a
```

Или (это уже добавил обращение массива):

```
#include "ttree.h"
int main()
{
    TernaryTree t = TT_create( TT_DEFAULTS, NULL );
    TT_Data data;
    size_t keys, i;

    TT_insert( t, "a", NULL );
    TT_insert( t, "aa", NULL );
    TT_insert( t, "b", NULL );
    TT_insert( t, "bb", NULL );

    data = TT_sorted_data( t );
    keys = TT_keys( t );

    for( i = 0; i < keys; i++ )
        printf( "%s\n", data[i].key );

    free( data );
    TT_destroy( t );
    return 0;
}
```

Выход:

```
a
aa
b
bb
```

Comment: Хм. А как выглядит структура вашего дерева?

Comment: Да самое стандартное троичное :) Выложил исходники, см. обновление.

Comment: В порядках обхода где-то корень потерялся - не?

Comment: Нет, корень нигде не теряется, просто в дампе не учитывается.

Comment: @klopp: А какая роль `splitter`'а? (Я не в курсе.)

Comment: Это то, с чем сравнивается очередной символ. Меньше - идём налево, равно - прямо, больше - направо :) P.S. http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex46.html , http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-search-tree/ и тд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваше дерево выглядит так:

```
    a
  / | \
 /  |  \
*  aa   b
       /|\
      / | \
     *  bb *
```

то вам нужен такой обход:

```
static void _TT_walk_preorder( TernaryTreeNode node, TT_Walk walker, void * data )
{
    if( node )
    {
        walker( node, data );
        _TT_walk_preorder( node->left, walker, data );
        _TT_walk_preorder( node->mid, walker, data );
        _TT_walk_preorder( node->right, walker, data );
    }
}
```

---

P.S.: Может быть, ещё пригодится такой обход (для случая, когда хочется отсотртированный список):

```
static void _TT_walk_inorder( TernaryTreeNode node, TT_Walk walker, void * data )
{
    if( node )
    {
        _TT_walk_inorder( node->left, walker, data );
        walker( node, data );
        _TT_walk_inorder( node->mid, walker, data );
        _TT_walk_inorder( node->right, walker, data );
    }
}
```

Comment: @klopp: Надеюсь, я правильно понял, что у вас за дерево вышло.

Comment: @klopp: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да! http://ato.su/resizer/i/9/f/4f201dd0.png Спасибо.

Comment: P.S. А какой баг вычислил valgrind... Закомментировано - его лечение: http://ato.su/resizer/i/0/9/5e68abbd.png